# Text on Button getting trimmed on some devices

Tags: android

Button has a text "Cancel" , on some Android devices like HTC Evo (OS 2.2) , instead of "Cancel" , only "Ca" is displayed.

Following is the button being put on the layout xml

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_upload"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btngray"
            android:shadowColor="@color/black"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
</Button>
```

The drawable being used is a nine patch image so that the button image adjusts the size according to the text. Is the layout:width & layout:height creating an issue?

Currently , unable to replicate the issue on the emulator or the devices I tested (HTC WildFire S , LG Optimus , Samsung Galaxy , etc.).

Any help/suggestions welcome.

Comment: can you give the cmplete layout may be problem could be other views params.

Answer (score 0):

Modify and add some attributes to your button's xml:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="none"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of you gave width in density pixel You need to give size as wrap_content so that button will take exact required size 
Change button code as follows

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_upload"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btngray"
            android:shadowColor="@color/black"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="1"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
</Button>
```